# viewDidDisappear called because of termination?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewdiddisappear

Normally `viewDidDisappear` is called in my app, because back button was pressed in navigation viewcontroller. But if app is terminated `viewDidDisappear` is called too. How can I make distinction between the two reason?

Comment: I am not sure whether it's possible to determine inside of the controller, but you can set some flag in 'UserDefaults' for example, then check it in 'AppDelegate', 'func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)'